# DAG with single source and sink

Tags: algorithm

I have to write an algorithm that find the path in DAG with single source and single sink...
I really don't know what to do ( tried to use DSF and topological sort but nothing...)
I don't want anyone to solve it for me but just some guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) finds shortest path in general unweighted graph - and also specifically in DAG [since it is also a graph]. It is also pretty simple to code it.

Note that DFS will find a path - but it doesn't have to be the shortest one.

You might also want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590299/how-can-i-find-the-actual-path-found-by-bfs) to see how to get the actual path from BFS after running it.

**EDIT:** according to your comments, it seems you want `O(|V|)` solution, and it doesn't have to be shortest. a modification of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) is the way to do then, since the DAG has a single source and a single sink, **every path from the source reaches the sink**.

Note that since your graph is a DAG and since we established that every path from the source reaches the sink, you don't need to go backward after exploring a certain path [so no recursion or stack is needed].

pseudo-code:

```
modifiedDFS(source,target):
  map <- new map
  current <- source
  while (current != target):
    next <- current.getNextVertex() //just chose an arbitrary edge and follow it, doesn't matter which
    map.put(next,current) //we "discovered" next by following current
    current <- next
```

after running this algorithm, you need to follow back the map from the target to the 
source - and you get the actual path [reversed of course]

The complexity is indeed `O(n)` because we visit each node at most once. In order to maintain `O(n)` the map has to be a hashmap [and not a treemap]. If the vertices are enumerated - you can even implement the map as an array.

Comment: I dont need to find the sourtest one.. just the one that will take O(n)

Comment: @Nusha: What is `n`? number of nodes in the graph?

Comment: @Nusha: DFS then gets you a `O(n)` solution in your case, I updated the answer with more details about it.