# Shortest Path Algorithm : Uniform distances from one point to adjacent points

Tags: java, algorithm, java-me, graph-theory, shortest-path

I am trying to develop an algorithm wherein I have a Location Class. In each class, I create a list of its adjacent Locations. I want to know, how can I get the shortest path from one Location to another. I am trying to look for different algorithms but it seems that they doesn't answer my problem.

For example, I have a point A and I want to go to point B,

```
A - - C - - H - - J
      |
      F- - K- -B
```

My idea for this is if B is in the List of adjacent locations of A, then that is the shortest path. If not, it should search the adjacent locations of the adjacent locations of A. But I do not know how to implement this in code or if it is a good algorithm. I also want to display A - C - F - K - B as the route for the shortest path. I am also developing this one on j2me so I am a bit limited on the java features that I can use.
If anyone can help me, it will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. What you describe is the start of [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). BFS is a shortest-path algorithm that is both [optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Optimality) [finds the shortest path] and [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Completeness) [always finds a path if one exist] for unweighted graph - so it is probably the right choice.

BFS works on graphs. In here your graph is `G = (V,E)` such that `V = {all locations}`  [the nodes/vertices/locations] and `E = {(u,v),(v,u) | u and v are neighbors}` [the edges/links/neighbors]

The idea of BFS is simpilar to what you are suggesting: first check if the starting node is also the target. Then check if one of the neighbors of the starting node is the target, then search for their neighbors....

Regarding **getting the actual path** from BFS: have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9590299/572670).

The idea is to maintain a map - for each node [location] - the map will indicate how did you get there? which node discovered it? After the BFS finished - follow the map from target to source, and you get the actual path [reversed of course]. The link provided gives more details about this idea.

Comment: I can understand what you mean but I am having a hard time translating it into Java code. Can you help me translate it even if for the pseudocode only? I have read some about BFS but the codes are very hard to understand.

Comment: @arthurbc: Did you have a look at the [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode) in the wikipedia page for it? Anything specific you are having troubles with? Did you understand how to model your problem as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29)?

Comment: Yes I have a look on the pseudo-code in the wikipedia. But maybe I don't know how to model my problem as a graph. Currently, I just have a list of Locations and each Locations has a list of its adjacent Locations. How can I use this so that I can apply the BFS algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is known in the computing world as a graph search problem, looking for the shortest path between two nodes. Graphs here are not the x and y axis graphs from math, but Nodes (or `Locations` in your example) connected by edges.

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is the most commonly used to find the shortest path between two nodes, and for your use case it is simplified slightly because the edges in your scenario all have a weight (or cost) of one. An implementation of this is available in [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.html), though I'm not sure how easy that is to include in a J2ME environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `A*` algorithm Dijkstra's pathfinding algorithm.

Comment: dijkstra is an overkill in here. it is harder to implement and takes longer run-time then a simple BFS - that is enough for unweighted graphs. Regarding A* - maybe I missed something, but the locations doesn't seem to be on a grid or something - which heuristic do you suggest fits here?