# A-Star algorithm (reconstruct path)

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I've managed to implement a* and i got the correct path.

The problem is how i can reconstruct the path from start to end, given that every node (from end to start) has a parent link, but not the first one, so my character doesn't know where to go first.

What I'm doing is returning the closed-list and starting from index 0 to x until I reach the end. This usually works well, but I know there's gotta be another way.

---

Also, what is the best way to check neighboring nodes?

I've made each node to create a rectangle and see if it intersects and that's how I know they're connected. I also use this technique with the player to know when a node has been reached.

Thanks!!

Comment: *"given that every node (from end to start) has a parent link, but not the first one"* - so, uh, give the first one a parent link then...

Comment: If you give the first one a parent link to the second one, the second one parent is still the first one, so it will generate an endless loop... I know what I can do, I was asking if there's a simple way (known) way to do it. I think I'll stick with the index i mentioned before.

Comment: I think you are not keeping track of parents correctly... the last node will have a `PreviousNode`, which will have a `PreviousNode`, which will have a `PreviousNode`... until the start, which has no `PreviousNode` (it's null).  That's your start square.  There's no endless loop, and there's no part of the path missing.  What are you doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your target node (You can simply cache it once it is found).

Go up the tree (using the `parent` field) until you find a node without it, this node is your root. The path you found by going up the links, is the shortest path in reversed order.

I once addressed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590299/how-can-i-find-the-actual-path-found-by-bfs), regarding BFS instead of A*

**EDIT**: A simple way to reverse the stack back to the original is to put the nodes in a stack while you go from target to source, and when you find the source - start popping elements out the stack.

Comment: Yeah, i know that. The problem is how i reconstruct the path when i get to the first node (the source) if it has no link to the second one (given that the parent link only works backwards).

Comment: @user1656222: You simply go from the *target* to the source backward and gets the reverse path. A simple way to reverse it back is to put all elements as you go in a stack, and when you are done - start popping the nodes from the stack.

Comment: Isn't the same if do it like i explained earlier? Return the closedList and just start from index 0 until reaching the end of the list?

Comment: Any thoughts about neighboring nodes? The rectangle thing works, but its a bit messy, but is useful when you have a map with scattered nodes around. If I divide the whole map into nodes, I can easily connect x node to it's neigbours by just looking at it's ID and doing id+-1 and id+-x depending on the wide of the map.

Comment: @user1656222: It really depends on the exact problem you have on hand