# BFS and UCS algorithms. My BFS implementation works but my UCS doesn't. Can't figure out why

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

As long as I am not mistaken, UCS is the same as BFS with the only difference that instead of expanding the shallowest node, it expands the node with the lowest path cost. (Also using PriorityQueue instead of Queue for that)So i copied my BFS code, created an extra Map to keep track of each node's path cost and only changed the way the items are being pushed/popped in the Queue/Priority Queue.

Note: getSuccessors(state) returns a list of triples (state, action, cost)

These are both of my implementations:

BFS:

```
def breadthFirstSearch(problem):
    """Search the shallowest nodes in the search tree first."""
    queue=Queue()
    objectQueue=Queue()
    visited=set()
    actions=[]
    flag=0
    objectMap={}
    actionMap={}
    start=problem.getStartState()
    objectMap[start]=start
    queue.push(start)
    objectQueue.push(start)
    if problem.isGoalState(start):
        return actions
    while queue:
        parent=queue.pop()
        object=objectQueue.pop()
        if parent in visited: continue
        visited.add(parent)
        if problem.isGoalState(parent):
                 while object!=start:
                        action=actionMap[object]
                        actions.append(action)
                        object=objectMap[object]
                 return actions[::-1]
        children=problem.getSuccessors(parent)
        for child in children:
                queue.push(child[0])
                objectQueue.push(child)
                objectMap[child]=object
                actionMap[child]=child[1]
        flag=1
    util.raiseNotDefined()
```

UCS:

```
def uniformCostSearch(problem):
    """Search the node of least total cost first."""
    queue=PriorityQueue()
    objectQueue=PriorityQueue()
    visited=set()
    actions=[]
    flag=0
    objectMap={}
    actionMap={}
    costMap={}
    start=problem.getStartState()
    costMap[start]=0
    objectMap[start]=start
    queue.push(start, 0)
    objectQueue.push(start, 0)
   if problem.isGoalState(start):
        return actions
   while queue:
        parent=queue.pop()
        object=objectQueue.pop()
        if parent in visited: continue
        visited.add(parent)
        if problem.isGoalState(parent):
                while object!=start:
                        action=actionMap[object]
                        actions.append(action)
                        object=objectMap[object]
                return actions[::-1]
        children=problem.getSuccessors(parent)
        for child in children:
                costMap[child]=costMap[object]+child[2]
                queue.update(child[0], costMap[child])
                objectQueue.update(child, costMap[child])
                objectMap[child]=object
                actionMap[child]=child[1]
        flag=1

    util.raiseNotDefined()
```

According to the autograder I'm provided with BFS works perfectly but my UCS fails. Here is the test that it fails at and its results:

```
        B1          E1
       ^  \        ^  \
      /    V      /    V
    *A --> C --> D --> F --> [G]
      \    ^      \    ^
       V  /        V  /
        B2          E2

    A is the start state, G is the goal.  Arrows mark 
    possible state transitions.  This graph has multiple
    paths to the goal, where nodes with the same state 
    are added to the fringe multiple times before they
    are expanded.

The following section specifies the search problem and the solution.
The graph is specified by first the set of start states, followed by
the set of goal states, and lastly by the state transitions which are
of the form: 

<start state> <actions> <end state> <cost>


start_state: A
goal_states: G
A 0:A->B1 B1 1.0
A 1:A->C C 2.0
A 2:A->B2 B2 4.0
B1 0:B1->C C 8.0
B2 0:B2->C C 16.0
C 0:C->D D 32.0
D 0:D->E1 E1 64.0
D 1:D->F F 128.0
D 2:D->E2 E2 256.0
E1 0:E1->F F 512.0
E2 0:E2->F F 1024.0
F 0:F->G G 2048.0

student solution:       ['1:A->C', '0:C->D', '0:E1->F']
student expanded_states:    ['A', 'B1', 'C', 'B2', 'D', 'E1', 'F', 'E2']

correct solution:       ['1:A->C', '0:C->D', '1:D->F', '0:F->G']
correct expanded_states:    ['A', 'B1', 'C', 'B2', 'D', 'E1', 'F', 'E2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You update costMap regardless of current values. Thus you repeatedly increase cost for not yet visited common successor of previously visited and current child.

Consider this example: start from A, end in C. There are nodes chain with cost 1 for each transition: A->A1->A2->A3->A4->A5->A6->A7->A8->A9->A10. Each of A nodes leads to B with cost 3. And B leads to C. You current implementation will update B's cost several times from at least 3 nodes (A, A1, A2), even though it's real cost is 3 (A->B).

You should check if child is in costMap, compare current costMap value to new one and only push into queue if new value is better. If costMap doesn't contain child, add it to costMap and queues.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you not constructing your successors correctly. you somehow got to e1 without getting there from D. i assume you are using dicts or lists. try to make your code use tuples only. this way you wont be passing around any references and muddling your code.

i would go with data that looks like below. first being the priority, second being the list of node's we have travelled and third being the next node to expand.

```
queue.push((2, (A, C), D))
```