# Adapting pseudocode to java implementation for finding the longest word in a trie

Tags: java, string, algorithm, trie

Referring to this question I asked: [How to find the longest word in a trie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191942/how-to-find-the-longest-word-in-a-trie)

I'm having trouble implementing the pseudocode given in the answer.

```
findLongest(trie):
 //first do a BFS and find the "last node"
 queue <- []
 queue.add(trie.root)
 last <- nil
 map <- empty map
while (not queue.empty()):
 curr <- queue.pop()
 for each son of curr:
    queue.add(son)
    map.put(son,curr) //marking curr as the parent of son
 last <- curr
//in here, last indicate the leaf of the longest word
//Now, go up the trie and find the actual path/string
curr <- last
str = ""
while (curr != nil):
      str = curr + str //we go from end to start   
    curr = map.get(curr)
return str
```

This is what I have for my method

```
public static String longestWord (DTN d) {
  Queue<DTN> holding = new ArrayQueue<DTN>();
  holding.add(d);
  DTN last = null;
  Map<DTN,DTN> test = new ArrayMap<DTN,DTN>();
  DTN curr;
  while (!holding.isEmpty()) {
       curr = holding.remove();

      for (Map.Entry<String, DTN> e : curr.children.entries()) {
          holding.add(curr.children.get(e));
          test.put(curr.children.get(e), curr);
      }
          last = curr;

      }
  curr = last;
  String str = "";
  while (curr != null) {
      str = curr + str;
      curr = test.get(curr);

  }
  return str;

  }
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException at:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, DTN> e : curr.children.entries())
```

How can I find and fix the cause of the NullPointerException of the method so that it returns the longest word in a trie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `curr.children.entries()` is not a null value. Perhaps, `DTN` returns a null value if that node has no children. This would cause your `NullPointerException`.

Try doing a quick check before you begin the iteration.

```
if(curr.children.entries() != null)
{
    //It's safe, so procede with going deeper into the trie.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Clark's answer, make sure that curr.children isn't null before dereferencing it.