# DFS Graph Recording Path (Pathfinding)

Tags: c++, graph, path-finding

i have implemented a simple DFS (non recursive) that 'tests' if a Path between **StartNode** and **EndNode** exists. It works as expected ( handling bidirectional/directional graphs ) - but i just can't figure out *how to store the Path* for later usage.

Currently i am debug-printing Visited nodes, but it's not what is should be storing.

Can somebody please help me out / shed a bit of light on - what exactly should i store and at what point to return a list of nodes from NodeStart to NodeEnd ?

Here is the example Graph:

[image: Graph]

Here is the DFS traversing function:

```
bool DFS(CNavigationGraph *pNavGraph, CNavigationGraphNode* pFromNode, CNavigationGraphNode* pToNode)
{
    assert(pNavGraph);
    assert(pFromNode);
    assert(pToNode);

    std::vector<CNavigationGraphNode*> vpVisitedNodes;
    std::vector<CNavigationGraphNode*> stack;

    stack.push_back(pFromNode);

    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        CNavigationGraphNode     *pTop = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        // Ok We've reached pToNode - means, path pFromNode to pToNode available
        if(pTop == pToNode)
        {
            for(int a = 0; a < vpVisitedNodes.size(); a++)
            {
                CLogger::Instance()->Write(XLOGEVENT_LOCATION, "{VISITED} %s",vpVisitedNodes[a]->GetNodeName().data());
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Add to visited list
        vpVisitedNodes.push_back(pTop);

        // Look for adjacent Nodes for pTop
        std::vector<CNavigationGraphNode*> vpAdjacentNodes;
        pNavGraph->GetAdjacentNodes(pTop->GetNodeName(), vpAdjacentNodes);
        for(int x = 0; x < vpAdjacentNodes.size(); x++)
        {
            // Add to stack if not visited
            if(IsVisited(vpVisitedNodes, vpAdjacentNodes[x]) == false)
                stack.push_back(vpAdjacentNodes[x]);
        }
    }

    // Path not found
    return false;
}
```

Here is the Debug Output:

Find Path Between Node1 and Node3

```
<main> [] DFS TRAVERSE TEST (DIRECTIONAL)
<DFS> [] {VISITED} Node1
<DFS> [] {VISITED} Node4
<DFS> [] {VISITED} Node5
<main> [] Path from Node1 to Node3 - YES
```

Find Path Between Node3 and Node1

```
<main> [] DFS TRAVERSE TEST (DIRECTIONAL)
<main> [] Path from Node3 to Node1 - NO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your algorithm correctly (and it is a DFS),
from the starting point you are taking a step to the direction of the first non-visited node. If there is no route to your target from that node, you step back and try to go to the next non-visited node, in the mean time carefully administrating which nodes were visited.

**All you need to add is a stack** to which you always push the node you are taking a step to,
and pop it from the stack if you had to step back. **This stack will store your route** from the start_node to the target. It also helps you to determine where to step back.

Here is your code, finally it grew a bit lengthier than I've thought but here it is:

```
// I call fromNode: start_node, toNode: target_node.

std::stack<CNavigationGraphNode*> DFS(CNavigationGraph *pNavGraph, CNavigationGraphNode* start_node, CNavigationGraphNode* target_node)
{
    using namespace std;

    stack<CNavigationGraphNode*> route; // route to target
    unordered_set<CNavigationGraphNode*> visited_nodes;  // hash set on who is visited
    vector<CNavigationGraphNode*> adjacent_nodes;

    CNavigationGraphNode* current_node = start_node;
    while(current_node!=target_node)
    {
      pNavGraph->GetAdjacentNodes(current_node->GetNodeName(), adjacent_nodes); 

      // "for each"; you can use any form of looping through the neighbors of current_node.
      bool found_non_visited = false;
      for(auto node : adjacent_nodes) 
      {
        if(visited_nodes.find(node) == visited_nodes.end())
        {
          route.push(current_node);
          visited_nodes.insert(node);
          current_node = node;
          found_non_visited = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(found_non_visited) 
        continue;

      if(route.empty())
        return route; // empty route means no route found
      current_node = route.pop();
    }
    route.push(target);
    return route;
}
```

And now you can `pop_back` your way from start to target or `pop` your way from target to start. If the route is empty, that corresponds to returning false from your original function.

[Reference on unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and [stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/), both in STL. It is implemented with a bucket has so it is much faster than set or map, which are usually implemented with red-black trees.

Remark: `std::unordered_set` is a C++11 extension, feel free to replace it with the slower `std::set` if you use C++03.

Answer (score 3):

Well, instead of having a `visited` *set* - you can have a `parent` *map* (map:Vertex->Vertex).

Modify the map while you traverse the graph, such that if you discovered node `v` from node `u`, add `parent[v] = u`. Init `parent[source] = NULL`.

Now, all you have to do is iterate (pseudo code):

```
current <- dest
while current != NULL:
   print current
   current <- parent[current]
```

It will give you the path in reversed order. You can store into to a stack (instead of the print statement) and iterate the stack if you want to achieve the original order of the path.

It is very similar to the idea explained for BFS in the thread: [How can I find the actual path found by BFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9590299/572670)

Comment: Using a stack is much cheaper than using a parent map.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: Maybe, but: (1) The advantage is minor because you are keeping a `visited` set anyway. I am not sure `visited` set + stack should be *much* more efficient then a `parent` map. (2) Using a `parent` map has some very important advantages over stack, mainly robustness. This approach fits well all graph discovery algorithms (like BFS), and lets you change the implementation from DFS to BFS with almost no effort, which is an important aspect.

Comment: Point taken on the first argument and I agree that BFS needs parent map (if you return when you've found a route, you may not want to return it). <br /> On the second argument: what do you mean by the stack not being robust?

Comment: I recommend you to consider using `std::unordered_map`. It is of O(1) complexity whereas `std::map` is of O(log n) at search/insert.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: I mean that a generic loop + collection traversal can be easily changed from DFS to BFS by simply changing the collection from stack to a queue. However, the stack solution does not fit well a BFS if you want to get the actual path, while a map does. Hope I am clear enough... If not, open a chat and I'll try to elaborate.